# Docker-Compose golang - No buildable Source

Tags: go, docker-compose

I've followed a couple of tutorials and am having trouble figuring out what i've done wrong.  I suspect its a very basic principal but that said as i'm new to both GoLang and docker-compose i'm not 100% sure which is my problem.

I'm running the golang:build docker image which just retrieves a couple github repositories.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The error is as follows:

```
+ exec go get -v -d
can't load package: package app: no buildable Go source files in /go/src/app
Service 'ddd' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper download' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The Docker-Compose file looks like this

```
ddd:
  build: ./goSvc
  working_dir: /go/src/
  command: go run main.go
  volumes:
    - ./goSvc/src/main.go:/go/src/main.go
    - ./goSvc/src/ddd:/go/src/ddd
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  environment:
    - DB_NAME=rnse
    - DEBUG=true
```

Go project structure

```
root
  goSvc
    pkg
    src
      ddd
        internal
          logic
        ...myGoFiles
      github.com
      main.go
    Dockerfile
```

Edit:
Including docker file for golang:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go get github.com/lib/pq
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: What's in `/go/src`?  There seems to be some confusion between `/goSvc` and `/go` in your question.  Typically there would be one location where Go is installed (lets say /usr/local/go) and then your Go workspace http://golang.org/doc/code.html which the GOPATH environment variable should point at.  It's not clear what's what in your question.  Maybe start without Docker first?

Comment: For me it looked like there was a problem while building docker image. Can you include it as well (Dockerfile)? And try build the image with docker command too

Comment: @GuySirton goSvc is just the folder i keep the local golang source in before it gets propagated out to the docker container.  root(pwd) = /home/highstead/projects/goSvc

Comment: @fuxi Attached, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image you used is used to automatically build Go app when building initial image.

Have a look at it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/3427e88341de17a4d8921b859180a2649e1ab96e/1.4/onbuild/Dockerfile). There is `ONBUILD COPY . /go/src/app` statement.

So you can either locate Dockerfile where `main.go` is located or use image without `ONBUILD` trigger and then run `go run` manually/with `docker-compose`.